# ffserver, ffmpeg, flowplayer - stream delay

Tags: streaming, ffmpeg, swf, delay

Good day to all I have a little problem with a stream.

I configured a ffmpeg to get a stream from vlc and then stream it again over http with ffserver.

Ok... the problem is this:

if I configure ffserver to encode as swf

```
 (

 Format swf

 VideoFrameRate x

 VideoSize 640x480

 etc.

 )
```

all is fine except the fact that the video size is set to something like 200x100 (not exactly but about that).

Ok... so I try as flv. Now it gets the correct dimensions but I have about 2 minutes delay.

Format flv

```
VideoCodec flv
```

same as in swf here

Can anyone give me a hit why? Or how to resolve the problem? (any of them)